# Why do I get a “Too many input arguments” error when passing in proper parameters?

Tags: matlab, oop, matlab-class

Why am I getting an error:

> ??? Error using ==> ensureCellType Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in ==> usage_dynamicVariableNaming at 11 result =
>   dataHolder.ensureCellType(str);

when I am passing in right number of parameters?

```
% USAGE:

clear all;
clc;

elementNames = {'area_12345[<>]6789', 'apollo123', 'guruX', 'ok'};
elementTypes = {'string', 'specialChar', 'int', 'float'};
elementValues = {'charlie', 'vvv', '09', '123.321'};

dataHolder = dynamicVariableNaming;

str = 'test';
result = dataHolder.ensureCellType(str);


%% CLASS
classdef dynamicVariableNaming
%HELLO Summary of this class goes here
%   - 

   properties           
           variableNames = [];           

           variableValues = [];
           variableTypes = [];
   end

   methods (Access = public) % (Access = private)
           function obj = dynamicVariableNaming (variableName, variableValue, variableType)
           % class constructor
               if(nargin > 0)
                 obj.variableNames = variableName;                 

                 obj.variableValues = variableValue;
                 obj.variableTypes = variableType;
               end
           end  
%    end
%            
%    methods (Static = true)
           function addVariables (obj, variableName, variableValue, variableType)
                 obj.variableNames = [obj.variableNames ensureCellType(variableName)];                 

                 obj.variableValues = [obj.variableValues ensureCellType(variableValue)];
                 obj.variableTypes = [obj.variableTypes ensureCellType(variableType)];
           end               

           function cellData = ensureCellType(value)       
            if (class(value) ~= 'cell') 
                cellData = cell2string(value);
            else
                cellData = value;
            end
           end            

   end   
end
```

---

Thanks for your great help.
It now runs, but the data is not inserted.

I started a new thread on this new issue:
[The data is not inserted successfully into object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212625/the-data-is-not-inserted-successfully-into-object)

Answer (score 6):

Unless you intend `ensureCellType` to be a Static method (in which case you should declare it with `(Static=true)`, you should give it the signature `cellData = ensureCellType(obj,value)`. `obj` gives you a reference to the object itself within the method.

You're getting the error you see because MATLAB is passing in both the object itself and `value` into your method, which is two input arguments rather than one.

If you will never need a reference to `obj` within the method, you can declare the method signature as `cellData = ensureCellType(~, value)`. Then MATLAB will know that it should have two inputs, but it can ignore passing in the first.

Comment: addVariables() is still giving errors.

======================================================

??? Error using ==> addVariables
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> usage_dynamicVariableNaming at 14
    dataHolder.addVariables(dataHolder, elementNames(i), elementTypes(i), elementValues(i));

Comment: You need to define your method signatures as `output = methodName(obj, otherInputs)`, but you need to call your methods as `output = obj.methodName(otherInputs)`. `obj` is passed in _implicitly_ as the first input argument - if you pass it in directly, there will be an extra input argument giving you the error you see.