# The data is not inserted successfully into object

Tags: oop, matlab

The data is not inserted successfully.

Output:

```
dataHolder.variableNames =      []
```

when it should be :

```
dataHolder.variableNames = [{'area_12345[<>]6789'}, {'apollo123'}, {'guruX'}, {'ok'}];
```

% USAGE:

```
elementNames = {'area_12345[<>]6789', 'apollo123', 'guruX', 'ok'};
elementTypes = {'string', 'specialChar', 'int', 'float'};
elementValues = {'charlie', 'vvv', '09', '123.321'};

dataHolder = dynamicVariableNaming;

str = 'test';
result = dataHolder.ensureCellType(str);


for i = 1:3
    dataHolder.addVariables(elementNames(i), elementTypes(i), elementValues(i));
end

dataHolder.variableNames

%%% CLASS

classdef dynamicVariableNaming
%HELLO Summary of this class goes here
%   - 

   properties           
           variableNames = [];           

           variableValues = [];
           variableTypes = [];
   end

   methods (Access = public) % (Access = private)
           function obj = dynamicVariableNaming (variableName, variableValue, variableType)
           % class constructor
               if(nargin > 0)
                 obj.variableNames = variableName;                 

                 obj.variableValues = variableValue;
                 obj.variableTypes = variableType;
               end
           end  
%    end
%            
%    methods (Static = true)
           function addVariables (obj, variableName, variableValue, variableType)

                 obj.variableNames = [obj.variableNames ensureCellType(obj, variableName)];                 

                 obj.variableValues = [obj.variableValues ensureCellType(obj, variableValue)];
                 obj.variableTypes = [obj.variableTypes ensureCellType(obj, variableType)];
           end               

           function cellData = ensureCellType(obj, value)   

            if (~strcmp(class(value), 'cell')) 
                cellData = {value};
                % cell2string(value); 
            else
                cellData = value;
            end
           end            

   end   
end
```

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark. Hovewer, your bug is simple... See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the changed opbject from the `addVariables` method as required when you are working with non-`handle` objects. Remember, matlab is different in comparison with other reference passing-based languages.

To fix it either make your class enherit from the `handle` class, or return `obj` from `addVariables`

Cant say if there are other problems in the code due to its poor formatting and inability to run in matlab (unbalanced ends, missing constructors, etc.)

Comment: You did it, KlausCPH !
Wow. 
Pardon, I am new to Matlab OO. The syntax has several differences to C#, Java, etc. 

I am extremely grateful.
Thank you, KlausCPH.

Comment: Glad to help. This difference trips almost everybody new to Matlab OO. Mathworks knows it and new versions of Matlab do therefore warn about this actually.